# Less: how to grab an entire ruleset from within a map

Tags: less

I have a nested ruleset (map) like the one below.

```
@typography: {
    @h1: {
        font: roboto;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 9.6rem;
        line-height: 9.6rem;
        text-transform:none;
    }
}
```

I know how to retrieve and output a single key such as [font], but is there any way of returning and outputting the whole of inner ruleset?

```
.myclass {
    font: roboto;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 9.6rem;
    line-height: 9.6rem;
    text-transform:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### "Can't work this way currently (v3.9)".

I'm afraid it's not going to work the way (specifically the map itself) it is.
Intuitively it would be something like:

```
#usage {
    @typography[@h1]();
}
```

But currently this feature (cascading `()` and `[]` operators) is not implemented.

A first-guess workaround like "assign a ruleset of interest to a temporary variable and then 'call' it" also fails:

```
#usage {
    @temp: @typography[@h1];
    @temp(); // error: not callable value
}
```

(This one actually to be counted as a bug - I [created](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/3382) a dedicated ticket).

This all brings us to the next section:

---

#### "Consider using mixin-based maps".

Notice that while "variable-based maps" (aka DRs) seem to be a more wide-spread pattern by now, there are [*five* different methods to define a map](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/3368#issuecomment-466562757) in Less (and infinite number of these methods permutations to define an N-dimensional (aka "nested") map).

Each method has its pros and cons, and so far it's not clear which one to be chosen as the "go-to" one (in a long run there's tendency to unify them as tidy as possible but so far it's far from that).

Now look at the structure you're trying to represent w/o sticking to "variable -> `@variable`" stereotype. Does not it look like a regular CSS ruleset:

```css
.typography {
    .h1 {
        font:         roboto;
        font-weight:     300;
        font-size:    9.6rem;
        line-height:  9.6rem;
        text-transform: none;
    }
}
```

?

And this way you've already got a "mixin-based map" you can use pretty much the same way you'd use a "variable-based map". (Actually the current [documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#maps-feature) for "Maps" also suggest both methods w/o enforcing either one as "the primary").
The only modification you'll need for this "CSS" structure is to make its inner or outer (or both) rulesets to be a parameteric mixin (by adding `()`) so that the rules won't appear in the compiled CSS by default.

E.g. like this:

```
.typography {
    .h1() {
...
```

Or like this:

```
.typography() {
    .h1 {
...
```

(Also if you prefer for these identifiers you can use `#` instead of `.`).

Now getting back to your use-case (**The Solution**):

```
.typography {
    .h1() {
        font:         roboto;
        font-weight:     300;
        font-size:    9.6rem;
        line-height:  9.6rem;
        text-transform: none;
    }
}

#usage-1 {
    // "expand" the set of rules:
    .typography.h1(); // OK
}

#usage-2 {
    // use individual value from the map:
    r: .typography.h1[font]; // OK
}

#usage-3 {
    // iterate through:
    each(.typography.h1(), <...>); // OK
}

// etc.
```

> Not a surprise counting that expanding a set of rules is what the mixins were invented for in the first place.

The only fundamental difference (beside current limitations/issues on how they can be used) between "variable-based" and "mixin-based" maps to keep in mind is that *"variables (and properties) override"* and *"rulesets (and thus mixins) cascade"*. This may affect some particular details when you'll need your CSS data to be customized/modified by "external code" (e.g. as in "theming/subtheming" etc.) - but that's another big story so I won't get into it here, although see the next section for some tips.

---

#### "Mixins and variables interop".

And one more important thing to understand about mixins (in context of the use-case).

If we'll think of variables as an abstract programming thing, i.e. "an identifier (symbolic name) associated with a value" we quickly see that a *mixin* is just that: *a variable*.

A "mixin" (its name) is really nothing but an identifier to refer to a value, i.e. -> *variable*.

It's just the identifier characters (`#` or `.` in front) plus a limitation on what kind of values it can hold is what makes it to be referred to by a different title, i.e. "mixin" instead of a "variable" (as in "Less `@variable`").

In other words, when it comes to "I have some data and I need something (i.e. "*a* variable") to hold/represent it", it's important to not automatically fall into the "*a* variable (in a generic sense) -> `@variable`" trap.

So getting back to the Q, another trick to have in mind is to know that mixin and variable values (specifically if it's a "ruleset" value) can be (almost) freely assigned/reassigned to each other. I.e. basically, you can create a variable to refer to a mixin-based map and create a mixin to refer to a variable-based map.
This may be valuable to overcome current issues/limitations (mostly in usage) of both methods (or if you just prefer more of `@`, `.` or `#` "code-look" where maps are used).

Here're a few tips:

```
// ................
// "Universal" map:

.typography {
    .h1() {
        font:         roboto;
        font-weight:     300;
        font-size:    9.6rem;
        line-height:  9.6rem;
        text-transform: none;
    }


    @h1:  {.typography.h1}; // assign mixin to variable
    .h2() {@h1()}           // assign variable to mixin
    .h3() {.typography.h1}  // assign mixin to mixin
    @h2:  @h1;              // assign variable to variable
}

@typography:  {.typography}; // assign mixin to variable
.graphytypo   {.typography}  // assign mixin to mixin
// etc.

// ................
// Usage:

#usage-1 {
    // use individual values from the map (all roboto):
    1: .typography.h1[font];
    2: .typography[@h1][font];
    3: .typography.h2[font];
    4: .typography.h3[font];
    5: .typography[@h2][font];

    6: @typography[@h1][font]; // <- like your original map

    7: .graphytypo.h3[font];

    // etc.
}

#usage-2 {
    // expand a set of .h1 rules (all the same):
    .typography.h1();
    .typography.h2();
    .graphytypo.h3();
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks (again) seven-seas-max. Great explanation and i'm sure I can come up with something similar based on the information you have provided.