# Less CSS: any default value for the new Map functionality?

Tags: less

I'm using the Map functionality in Less CSS, typically like this:

```
@component-themes: {
    button: secondary;
    top-app-bar: primary-light;
}

.get-component-theme(@component) {
    return: @component-themes[$@component];
}

// This will fail compilation
//
@my-button: .get-component-theme(non-existent-button)[];
```

However, if the property doesn't exist, the compilation fails. While this is sometimes what is required, there are other occasions when it would be better to return a default value and carry out an alternative action.

I've scoured the Less site but can't find any indication that this functionality exists, but that doesn't mean there's not a way to achieve it.

Anyone know?

Comment: No, there's no such feature. Basically this is related to [#1400](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1400) (e.g. for your example you could do a (mixin-based) map of default values unless your goal is to "parse" random custom data).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - what exactly do you mean by a "mixin based map" - isn't that what I have above?

Comment: No, above you have pretty useless (what is it for?) mixin wrapper on top of the variable map. For a mixin-based map see this [A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55519465/2712740) (one of the pros of the MBM is that custom data values may override default data values only *partially* due cascading...).