# How to nest variables with LESS

Tags: css, sass, less

I'm used to working with `sass` when working with projects. However I need to use `less` for a specific project. Is there a way to nest variables with `less` like the following example?

```
$palettes: (
    brand: (
        base: #ffffff,
        dark: #a31f02,
        green: #61a143
    )
);
```

Then can be used like:

`$color-link: palette(brand);`

Comment: See [Maps](http://lesscss.org/features/#maps-feature).

Comment: For a certain non obvious "map" details also see this [A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55519465/2712740) (it answers the directly opposite Q but right after the first part it is about generic understanding of the related Less structures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve the situations is a [map](http://lesscss.org/features/#maps-feature). It is a new feature in Less lang that allows you to get values using keys