# Less: data structures (mixins, maps, lists)

Tags: variables, less

I'm working on a website which is using profile images in different sizes and i was wondering if i could make use of less lists.

What I want to achieve is something like that (simplified):

```
profile_image = {
    "thumbnail" : {"width": 200, "height" : 100},
    "large"     : {"width": 800, "height" : 600},
}
```

in my Less Class:

```
div.image
{
    @profile-image['large']
}
```

which should result in

```
div.image
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

what would be the best practice for it?

Comment: As far as I understand you need a structure/object/map to store/define some values in a more human-readable manner. Now the trick is just to forget the JavaScript syntax )the quotes in particular) and take a close look at your `div.image` code. Right, *this* is the syntax you'd define a structured data in Less. (Obviously there're also lists aka array but that type of data is not quite suitable for your particular case).

Comment: [Example](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/7656bd72fd7730e49c59432372358ffb). Now you can traverse through the values of this map (using e.g. [`each` function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-each)) and build whatever CSS code you need. In general start with: [Maps](http://lesscss.org/features/#maps-feature). Also see [five different methods to define a map](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/3368#issuecomment-466562757) and [further tips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55519465/2712740) on "variable-based vs. mixin-based maps" usage.

Comment: And finally ("getting back to lists"). Sure, if in this particular case you have just two "attributes" per image, it does not make too much sense to bloat your structures with these repeating `width/height` identifiers. So you'll always can use a list to define them. [Example](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/c771d404fe9d4523233c94d2b7a9a46d).

Comment: And an after-final example to match your `@profile-image['large']` snippet: [mixin-based-map fits just perfect](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/ac840819a2a19b9e688089107a758286). (Technically it's not even a "map" as such but "a set of mixins in a namespace" - same structure - just different "names" depending on how it's used). **<- Probably this one could be an answer** (if I'd only could decide how to handle the "best practice" thing - which is just too wide/generic wording for such a trivial thing like "copy something from one {} to another {}").